# Does anyone know the origin of the phrase "walk it off"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, slang

Ex. When someone gets hurt, usually in sports, and someone tells you to "walk it off"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this phrase really has an origin.  In the case you described, it's used literally, rather than metaphorically, and simply refers to the fact that walking relieves aches / pains in the legs.

(If this was used metaphorically, then the origin of the phrase could be said to be "from the sports / exercise world".)

Also see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-the-saying-walk-it-off

Comment: It's a set phrase, so it's not literal.  If it were, "to walk it off" would mean to walk some thing away.  It means that walking will cure minor injuries.  It would seem to originate in sports, although it's clear that walking is the surest way to make some minor injuries (like a sprained ankle) worse.  Your link provides no evidence of origin, but it does have a misuse of the phrase.